# How to extract a XML to a table with recurring rows

Tags: python, xml

I have a XML that roughly looks like the example below. I want to transfer that XML into a table where every possible combination is written into a row (see Table example). What would be the most efficient way to do that? Or is it even possible/feasible?

XML-example:

```
<root>
    <child1>
        <var1 value="1"/>
        <var2 value="2"/>
        <nest1>
            <var3 value="a"/>
            <var4 value="b"/>
            <nest2>
                <var5 value="I"/>
                <var6 value="II"/>
            <nest2/>
            <nest2_1>
                <var5 value="III"/>
                <var6 value="IV"/>
            <nest2_1/>
        <nest1/>
        <nest1_2>
            <var3 value="c"/>
            <var4 value="d"/>
            <nest2_2>
                <var5 value="I"/>
                <var6 value="II"/>
            <nest2_2/>
            <nest2_3>
                <var5 value="III"/>
                <var6 value="IV"/>
            <nest2_3/>
        <nest1_2/>
    <child1/>
    <child2>
        <var1 value="4"/>
        <var2 value="5"/>
        <nest1>
            <var3 value="a"/>
            <var4 value="b"/>
            <nest2>
                <var5 value="I"/>
                <var6 value="II"/>
            <nest2/>
            <nest2_1>
                <var5 value="III"/>
                <var6 value="IV"/>
            <nest2_1/>
        <nest1/>
        <nest1_2>
            <var3 value="c"/>
            <var4 value="d"/>
            <nest2_2>
                <var5 value="I"/>
                <var6 value="II"/>
            <nest2_2/>
            <nest2_3>
                <var5 value="III"/>
                <var6 value="IV"/>
            <nest2_3/>
        <nest1_2/>
    <child2/>
</root>
```

Table-example:

```
|var1|var2|var3|var4|var5|var6|
|:--:|:--:|:--:|:--:|:--:|:--:|
|1   |2   |a   |b   |I   |II  |
|1   |2   |a   |b   |III |IV  |
|1   |2   |c   |d   |I   |II  |
|1   |2   |c   |d   |III |IV  |
|3   |4   |a   |b   |I   |II  |
|3   |4   |a   |b   |III |IV  |
|3   |4   |c   |d   |I   |II  |
|3   |4   |c   |d   |III |IV  |
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you tried something already? Are you completely stuck?

Comment: Thank you! I am completely stuck on how to deal with such a complex and deeply nested XML. I only have experience in converting shallow XMLs.

Answer (score 0):

The given xml contains typos in case of closing tags (wrong positioned backslashes), but after fixing this you might collect the column data in the following way:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

tree=ElementTree.parse('test.xml') # I put the corrected xml in this file
column_names=['var%i'%(i+1) for i in range(6)] # create a list of column names
result={}
for column_name in column_names:
    values=tree.findall('.//*/%s'%column_name) # get a list of all related xml objects (using xpath syntax)
    result[column_name]=[item.get('value') for item in values] # collect the values for each column
print(result)
>{'var6': ['II', 'IV', 'II', 'IV', 'II', 'IV', 'II', 'IV'], 'var2': ['2', '5'], 'var1': ['1', '4'], 'var5': ['I', 'III', 'I', 'III', 'I', 'III', 'I', 'III'], 'var4': ['b', 'd', 'b', 'd'], 'var3': ['a', 'c', 'a', 'c']}
```

Sorry I did not spend any effort in creating the tabular output, because your question went in the direction of extracting the data from the nested xml file.